# Cannot create a dataset with multiple tables joined in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am moving data from On-premise SQL DB to Azure cloud.
I have a problem creating a dataset in Azure data factory(V2) with multiple tables joined. I can select only one table while creating a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the table joined query to get the data as Source dataset in Data Factory.

For example, here's the query joined two tables emp and tb1 :

[image]

Create On-premise SQL Server Source dataset:

[image]

Using query to get the dataset which joined multiple table:

```
select eno,ename,age from emp left join tb1 on emp.eno=tb1.id
```

[image]

Hope this helps.